# How to insert in database inside multi threads java

Tags: java, multithreading, insert, hsqldb

I have a task. I need to randomly generate numbers between 1 and 1000000 and insert it to table called 'numbers' in database.
Table 'numbers' has two columns: 'number' and 'quantity'
If the number already existing in database, I need to increment quantity in the table.
I have tried it in this way:

```
public void insertRow(String number) throws SQLException {
        int cnt = getCount(number);
        if (cnt == 0) {
            insert(number);
        } else if (cnt > 0) {
            update(number);
        }
    }
```

getCount checking if number is existing in database:

```
private int getCount(String number) throws SQLException {
        int cnt = 0;
        String sql = "select count(number) as cnt from \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER where number='" + number + "'";
        Statement sta = getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            cnt = rs.getInt("cnt");
        }

        return cnt;
    }
```

Inserting to database:

```
private boolean insert(String number) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "insert into \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER (number, qty) values(?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
                ps.setString(1, number);
                ps.setInt(2, 0);
                ps.addBatch();
                ps.executeBatch();
                getConnection().commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                try {
                    getConnection().rollback();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
                }
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And updating:

```
private boolean update(String number) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "update \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER set (qty) = (?) where number = ?";
        int qty = selectQtyByNumber(number) + 1;
        PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
                ps.setInt(1, qty);
                ps.setString(2, number);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                getConnection().commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                try {
                    getConnection().rollback();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
                }
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

SelectQtyByNumber method gets current quantity of number

```
private int selectQtyByNumber(String number) throws SQLException {
        int qty = 0;
        String sql = "select qty from \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER where number='" + number + "'";
        Statement sta = getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            qty = rs.getInt("qty");
        }
        return qty;
    }
```

When I run this code I always get BatchUpdateException: integrity constraint violation. But some number's quantity increases. Why is it happening? How to deal with it? Database is HSQLDB.

This is my Database constructor and getConnection method

```
public Database(String url, String user_name, String password) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");

            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user_name, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            LOGGER.error("Database initialization exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that JDBC package classes are not thread safe.  If you're sharing connections between threads you've got a problem.

The details around connection acquisition are crucial.  You hide them in your `getConnection()` method.  Are they pooled?  Does every operation get a fresh new `Connection` instance?  Where are those being closed?

Your second problem is isolation.  You need to set the connection isolation to the highest level possible: SERIALIZABLE.  You can't interleave reads and writes properly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question with getConnection method. I am sorry, but I am really newbie with multithreading. Can I create connection pool with my hsqldb driver?

Comment: Find a connection pool class. Apache has one.

Answer (score 1):

You rely too much on Java code. Your code can be simplified, but you can use a completely different approach with the MERGE statement and allow HSQLDB to handle the whole thing. This statement can be used with auto-commit and is thread safe.

```
MERGE INTO public.unique_number
USING VALUES (CAST(? AS VARCHAR(100)), CAST(? AS INTEGER)) AS vals(number, quantity)
ON unique_number.number = vals.number
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET number = vals.number
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (number, quantity) VALUES vals.number, valse.quantity;
```

See the Guide
http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Comment: Not ANSI SQL.  Will this work with databases other than Hypersonic?  Are there analogous constructs in other relational databases?  If yes, it could just be a matter of database-dependent SQL.

Comment: This is ANSI syntax and supported by many other databases. For MySQL there is INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY clause.